# Plotting two functions in the same figure with different scales on the two x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

I want to plot two different functions in the same figure. However I want them to use different scales on their x-axis. 
One scale shoudl just show the values of x and the others will have to show seconds in the end.

Right now I have this

```
k=5
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_xlabel(r"values of x")  #adds description to scale on bottom
ax2 = ax1.twiny()       #adds the seconds scale on top

x = np.arange(0.1, 1.5, 0.1)    #values of x for function are in range
y = k*(np.power(x,(k-1))) * np.exp(-(np.power(x,(k-1))))    #that is the function I want to draw
ax1.plot(x,y)       #draw function 
tx = x
ty = x*7
ax2.plot(x,x*7)

ax2.set_xlabel(r"time in seconds")
ax2.set_xlim(1484)      #set limit of time  
ax2.invert_xaxis()      #invert it so that it works like we want to
ax1.set_xlim(0.1,1.4)       #set limit for the x axis so that it doesn't skale on its own.
plt.show()
```

I am sorry but I could not properly insert the code. 
The ax2 function is right now just a dummy. I just want to be able to see it and also in the end change the scale of the ax2 to my time frame.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure your code doesn't work :-p

Your dummy function for ax2 is not good enough, I replaced it with `ax2.plot(x*1000,x*50)` to be able to see it.

And I do the plotting after the rescaling :

```
k=5
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_xlabel(r"values of x")  #adds description to scale on bottom
ax2 = ax1.twiny()       #adds the seconds scale on top

x = np.arange(0.1, 1.5, 0.1)    #values of x for function are in range
y = k*(np.power(x,(k-1))) * np.exp(-(np.power(x,(k-1))))    #that is the function I want to draw
ax1.plot(x,y)       #draw function 
tx = x
ty = x*7


ax2.set_xlabel(r"time in seconds")
ax2.set_xlim(1484)      #set limit of time  
ax2.invert_xaxis()      #invert it so that it works like we want to
ax2.plot(x*1000,x*50)
ax1.set_xlim(0.1,1.4)       #set limit for the x axis so that it doesn't skale on its own.
plt.show()
```

Which gives :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The second plot is hidden behind the left Y axis. You will be able to see it if you use a thicker line and/or markers:

```
ax2.plot(x,x*7, '-o', lw=5)
```

[image: A plot]

You could as well change the x limits of `ax2` but you went out of your way to make it as it is so I guess it is exactly as you want it to be.